# No matching code signing identity found. Deploying to ios device for the first time

Tags: ios, xcode

Cant manage to run my app on my device.

Ive registered my apple ID yesterday to the developer program, also used my device in the "Organizer" for developing.

In my main project General settings im trying to change the "Team" - It wont find my account.
When im pushing the "Fix issue" button it also reacts like i dont have a registerd developing account.

[image]

When i push the Add.. i can see that my developer apple id is already in the accounts:

[image]

As you can see my Apple ID is already signed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a provisioning profile

Check this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86A7wcJxOqM

Hope this should help.